# Тонкости разработки изометрических игр

Tags: разработка-игр, pascalabc.net

Полазив в гугле и немного по стэку, так и не нашёл внятно изложенных способов создания изометрии. А те что есть, просто обрываются на пoлycлoвe. Единственное, что более менее внятно объяснено это матрица (простейший двумерный массив из 0 и 1) уровней и преобразование координат с изоометрческих в обычные. Но как одно с другим состыковать решительно непонятно

P.s: загуглив нерусские мануалы, наткнулся на сей исходник (https://k3no.medium.com/isometric-grids-in-python-40c0fad54552), решивший мой вопрос. Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно в чем ваш вопрос. Можете как-то проиллюстрировать, в чем именно затруднения?

Comment: вопрос - как сделатку сетку ?

Comment: Что значит "как сделать сетку"? Берете холст, рисуете на нем линии - вот вам сетка. Итерируетесь по первой оси (X), вычисляете точку начала (X=0.0 Y=0.0), точку конца линии (X=0.0 Y=99.0) - рисуете. X=1.0 и т.д.. Потом так же по второй оси (Y).

Comment: Могу предположить, что если некая часть объекта представлена NxN пикселями, то при  удалении (объект приближается к горизонту) ее надо отображать MxM пикселями (M < N). Наверное основная тонкость состоит в выборе тех пикселей, которые надо выбрасывать

Comment: @avp удаление? В классической игровой изометрии нет перспективы и уменьшения объектов при удалении.

Comment: @Kromster, а тогда что это такое -- "игровая изометрия"?

Comment: @avp вот прямо так вводите в гугл "игровая изометрия" и переключайтесь на картинки ;-) То что вы имеете ввиду с M-N это скорее перспектива (как в старых DOS гонках с видом из кабины)

Comment: @avp вбивайте «Snake Rattle ’n’ Roll» и наслаждайтесь 

Comment: @andreymal, я понял. Кажется, раньше это называли псевдо-3D